# Angular 11 application not getting authenticated by Microsoft Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure-active-directory

I'm a beginner in Azure Active Directory Authentication concept.

I'm trying to implement Azure Active Directory Authentication in an existing "Angular - Web API Core" application (***Multi-tenant***).

I've implemented everything as per instructions from Microsoft Azure Active Directory Docs.

Still the "***AuthenticationResult***" is getting returned as NULL on the Angular Client side of the application after the "***loginRedirect***" method is getting invoked. (*No application specific Web API call is getting invoked here*).

***Issue***: Application Login Page => On clicking the "Login" button user is navigated to ***Microsoft Azure Login Page*** => Providing the credential and user is getting re-directed back to the ***application Login page*** and NOT to the ***registered RedirectURI***

Providing below the structure of the application:

```
authService => instance of MsalService.
msalBroadCastService => instance of MsalBroadcastService.
msalGuardConfig => instance of MsalGuardConfiguration.
isUserLoggedIn: boolean = false;
```

1. app.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(): void {

this.authService.handleRedirectObservable().subscribe({
      next: (result: AuthenticationResult) => { // few console log code snippet },
      error: (error) => console.log(error)
    });
}
```

2. login.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
// have tried the following with "handleRedirectPromise" also, but it didn't work.

this.authService.handleRedirectObservable().subscribe({
            next: (result: AuthenticationResult) => {
                this.msalBroadCastService.inProgress$
                    .pipe(
                        filter((status: InteractionStatus) => status === InteractionStatus.None),
                        takeUntil(this.destroy$)
                    )
                    .subscribe((x) => {
                        // the component "redirect-path" is the redirectURI mentioned in the application configuration file and also in the Azure Active Directory redirectURI section.
                        if (result)
                            this.router.navigate(['redirect-path']);
                    })
            },
            error: (errorMsg) => {
                debugger;
                console.log(errorMsg)
            }
        });
....
....
// Existing logic to load the application "Login" page.
}

onLogin(){
this.authService.instance.handleRedirectPromise()
            .then((tokenResponse) => {
                if (!tokenResponse) {
                    this.isUserLoggedIn = this.authService.instance.getAllAccounts().length == 0;
                    if (this.isUserLoggedIn) {
                        this.authService.loginRedirect({ ...this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest } as RedirectRequest);
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

3. app.module.ts

```
MsalModule.forRoot(new PublicClientApplication(
      {
        auth: {
          clientId: '<Client ID>',
          redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200/#/redirect-path',
          authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations'
          // authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common' // Tried this also, but didn't work.
        },
        cache: {
          cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
          storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE
        },
        system: {
          loggerOptions: {
            loggerCallback: (level: LogLevel, message: string, containsPii: boolean): void => {
              if (containsPii) {
                return;
              }
              switch (level) {
                case LogLevel.Error:
                  console.error(message);
                  return;
                case LogLevel.Info:
                  console.info(message);
                  return;
                case LogLevel.Verbose:
                  console.debug(message);
                  return;
                case LogLevel.Warning:
                  console.warn(message);
                  return;
              }
            },
            piiLoggingEnabled: false
          },
          windowHashTimeout: 60000,
          iframeHashTimeout: 6000,
          loadFrameTimeout: 0,
          asyncPopups: false
        }
      }
    ),
      {
        interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
        authRequest: {
          scopes: ['user.read']
        }
      },
      {
        interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
        protectedResourceMap: new Map(
          [
            ['https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']]
          ]
        )
      }    
    )

providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MsalInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }, MsalGuard    
  ]
```

4. app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  // { path: '', component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [MsalGuard] },
  { path: 'redirect-path', component: RedirectPathComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  // { path: 'redirect-path', component: RedirectPathComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [MsalGuard] },
]
```

5. index.html

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <app-redirect></app-redirect>
</body>
```

Please do let me know if any other configuration related information is required (that I might have missed).

Your guidance will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are there any errors or messages in your browser console? What does your Network tab look like? Are you using OIDC or SAML (or something else?) as your protocol for comms with Azure AD?

Comment: @Dai - No there are no error messages in my browser console. The protocol for communication is whatever mentioned in **app.module.ts**. Being in Angular it is a Single Page Application, where I found that, that is how you have to configure the authentication and protocol steps. Network tab is making 2 POST method calls: 1) http://localhost:4200/sockjs-node/info?t=1654666443666 and 2) http://localhost:4200/sockjs-node/558/k5vriwfl/xhr_streaming?t=1654777454371 and both are returning OK status code of 200

Comment: `socksjs-node` is for WebSockets, not AAD.

Comment: I think the problem is you're using `http://localhost:4200`. What happens if you use `https://localhost:4200` instead? (you can use a self-signed certificate: PowerShell now does it with a single cmdlet) - (you'll also need to update your AAD application registration with the updated URIs).

Comment: @Dai - I don't think the issue is with 'http' and 'https'. Because, initially when I was not using the ***login.component.ts*** file, AAD was redirecting me to the correct RedirectURI. Things started to stop working, when I introduced the ***login.component.ts*** file (due to other application related requirements) and shifted the AAD related codes in here.

Comment: The reason I think it's to do with `https` is because your `app.module.ts` file shows you're using OIDC (with Implicit Flow?), and OIDC pretty-much requires `https` for most flows and grants, _especially_ when using the OIDC front-channel and Implicit flow. Have you used the AAD troubleshooting tools in the Azure Portal and/or contacted AAD for support?

Comment: @Dai - Have selected both "Access tokens (used for implicit flows)" and "ID tokens (used for implicit and hybrid flows)" in Azure Portal (actually tried both one by one and now have selected both, but nothing is working). No the troubleshooting "Technical" options are not available for the free version.

Comment: Have you tried using [the Azure AD Test environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/test-setup-environment)? Also, are you doing this AAD integration work professionally? (i.e. are you being paid to do this?) if so, then complain to your boss that they **need** to get you _at least_ [an Azure Developer Support plan](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/plans/) (it's only $30/mo) - that should unblock you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi [Debasmita](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19295131/debasmita) you should not clear all data stored in localstorage while initializing LoginComponent. This is because PublicClientApplication is configured to use local storage (cacheLocation: 'localStorage')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).